# iMacros FF Eval If Else .match .replace regex capturing group is ignored

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements, eval, imacros

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\";
if(!s.match(/.*>\s*(\d+).*/)) {s.replace=(/.*>\s*(\d+).*/,'$1');}
else {s.replace=/.*>\s*(\D+).*/,'$1';}")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

I am trying to check whether the extracted HTML code (matching either the first or second snippet) matches a string of numeric characters "11111" outside the html tags and if it does, replace it with the 1st capturing group of said match ('$1'):

```html
<td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">
              11111      <img src="/images/flaggen/de.png" name="" alt="" width="16" height="11" align="absmiddle">       SomeText                  (MoreText)                </td>
```

If it does not match, replace it with the string of non-numeric characters "SomeText" again using the first capturing group ('$1'):

```html
<td style="outline: 1px solid blue;">
                        <img src="/images/flaggen/de.png" name="" alt="" width="16" height="11" align="absmiddle">       SomeText                  (MoreText)                </td>
```

The regex matches in both cases and does replace the string BUT only returns literally

> $1

, or whatever I try to replace with.

No other regex I have tried worked (returns just the literal regex expression), neither did $&.

How can I sucessfully reference a capturing group in this expression?

Edit 1: Using $1 without quotes returns literraly `$1`, using double quotes "$1" returns iMacro error `MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line 42 (Error code: -910)`. Escaping the double quotes `\"$1\"` returns again literally `$1`.

Comment: @Toto  Without quotes iMacros returns `$1 is not defined, line: 42 (Error code: -1001)`

Comment: @Toto I have tried that before, with "" I get `MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line 42 (Error code: -910) `, escaping with \$1 does not work, neither does /$1/

Comment: @Toto Tried that too, the return is `$1`. I will edit my question to include your suggestions and their outcomes.

Comment: I need clarification here: Your !EXTRACT holds one of the code snippets, what would want to have as the output after the EVAL is done? What should !VAR1 contain in each case respectively?

Comment: @PinkiePie In case 1 VAR1 should contain the string of numbers extracted from the HTML code e.g. '11111'. In case 2 it should be the string of text  e.g. 'SomeText'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, try the following `EVAL` command:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; if(s.match(/.*>\s*(\d+).*/)) {s = s.match(/.*>\s*(\d+).*/)[1];} else {s = s.match(/.*>\s*(\D+)\\(/)[1].trim();} s;")
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem, but I wonder if you could elaborate how to reference the capturing group using .match/.replace.